# Debugging Model class in C# code

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-debugging

I am working on Entity Framework with Oracle database. I have Long POCO class, that I have generated using POCO generating tools. Now I am getting error of Specified cast is not valid

```
An exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
```

and I know is error is due to some attribute in model class as I have figure one out, however class is too big and I have want to what I can enable in debugging to find source of error, as degugging tells error generated at line where I am calling repository method but I know error is not there, is in model class, so basically I want to debugging to tell me attribute name where casting error occurs

[image]

### POCO class where error actually is

```
[Table("abc.PEOPLE")]
public class PeopleEntity
{
    [Key]
    public int PERSON_CODE { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string FORENAME { get; set; }

    [StringLength(240)]
    public string MIDDLE_NAMES { get; set; }

   //remain attributes...........
```

Comment: There is too much abstraction here for us to say anything useful. The code that throws this exception is hidden in a repository you don't show, and the error itself is probably thrown by Entity Framework, meaning you have data in some column of some row that can't be mapped to the destination type.

Comment: What that Get funtion will return

Comment: that is correct and I know one of them, off course it took me time to figure out one. so I want to know how I make debugger tell me column name where actually miss cast happening.

Comment: I don't want to solve error as I know answer for that already, my question is regarding to debugging level

Comment: Get function call unit of work followed by generic interface --> DbContext and data

Comment: Please refer to this blog about how to debug EF POCO mapping issue: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/alexj/2010/02/11/tip-53-how-to-debug-ef-poco-mapping-issues/